# Migrating a running production server to Xen, unmodified as a second HDD?

Tags: linux, centos, virtualization, xen

I have a production server which I am looking to virtualize via XEN. For this purpose I have purchased a new Sata HDD, in which I have promptly installed CentOS 5.5 x64 with XEN server installed. Now I have two HDD: /dev/sda1 running as host with Xen Server Installed; and /dev/sda2 which is the HDD where the original server has installed.

[image]

Is it posible to use /dev/sda2 to work as GuestOS in a xen server? Would I have to modify its kernel?

Thank you for any input

Answer (score 0):

Yes the domU system needs a xen kernel. after installing the xen kernel you should be able to use /dev/sda2 as a guest server.

Comment: Allrigh time for an update. After reading topdogs answer and researching online I found that it is in fact possible to do so in a fully virtualized environment. How